# Web3 balance is showing OmiseGo balance but not Bitball

Tags: web3js, erc-20, balances, web3js-v1.x

You can see on Etherscan that I have 2 types of tokens in my wallet:

https://etherscan.io/address/0xb8fd65fc6919c5b97453eaba6b895144597985b2#tokentxns

`2.3 OmiseGo` and `10,000 Bitball`

I have a short script to get the balance of ERC20 contracts, which works perfectly when I lookup my `OmiseGo` balance, but returns 0 for my `Bitball` balance.

```
let btb_token_address =     "0x382117315856a533549ea621542ccce13e54ae82";
let omisego_token_address = "0xd26114cd6EE289AccF82350c8d8487fedB8A0C07";
let walletAddress =         "0xb8fd65fc6919c5b97453eaba6b895144597985b2";
// The minimum ABI to get ERC20 Token balance
let minABI = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"mintingFinished","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"unpause","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"mint","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"paused","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"balance","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"finishMinting","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"pause","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_amount","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_releaseTime","type":"uint256"}],"name":"mintTimelocked","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"},{"name":"_spender","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"name":"remaining","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Mint","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[],"name":"MintFinished","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[],"name":"Pause","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[],"name":"Unpause","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"}];
// Get ERC20 Token contract instance

let contract = web3.eth.contract(minABI).at(btb_token_address);
//let contract = web3.eth.contract(minABI).at(omisego_token_address ); //working

// Call balanceOf function
contract.balanceOf(walletAddress, (error, balance) => {
  // Get decimals
  contract.decimals((error, decimals) => {
    // calculate a balance
    balance = balance.div(10**decimals);
    console.log(balance.toString());
  });
});
```

Why is my script returning 0 for Bitball?

Comment: `10**decimals > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`

Comment: And note that in web3.js v1.x, `BigNumber` has been replaced with `BN`, which supports only integer values, so you cannot use `div` either (it will just truncate the result to 0).

Comment: Add `bignumber.js` or `decimal.js` to your `package.json` file, and use one of them instead.

Comment: Something like `balance = new BigNumber(balance.toString() + "e-" + decimals.toString());`.

Comment: @goodvibration thanks for your suggestion, I have added the bignumber CDN and your latest comment but I am still seeing a balance of 0. Before I format the number to be the correct decimal place, I receive a 0 value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where did you get the 0x382117315856a533549ea621542ccce13e54ae82 address from?

If you click BitBall token in your token list, you'll notice that it leads to 
https://etherscan.io/token/0x06e0feb0d74106c7ada8497754074d222ec6bcdf?a=0xb8fd65fc6919c5b97453eaba6b895144597985b2

So the real token address is 0x06e0feb0d74106c7ada8497754074d222ec6bcdf

Comment: Oops! That makes sense, it seems like there are a few fake BTB tokens, that is frustrating